# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/SharedCacheMode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement an application utilizing Spring mvc and Spring data. When I try to persist objects everything is working fine but when I want to deploy the application on a server I get an exception as below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Failed to introspect bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/SharedCacheMode
```

The pom.xml is

```
 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Hopper-SR4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId> mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And applicationContext is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.amir"/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/amirdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.tsi"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <!--<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" />-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tsi"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

For mvc two other Spring Congfig file are used which are rootContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml"/>
</beans>
```

and The dispatcher-servlet is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="conversionService"
          class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
                <property name="maxPageSize" value="3"/>
            </bean>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
        <constructor-arg name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.its" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In entity classes I used `import javax.persistence.*;` to enable `@Entity` annotation. I think, maybe I am mixing different versions and tried to read related documentation but I did not find anything. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

to your `pom.xml`

EDIT:

Add

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I did, but now I got  javax/persistence/ValidationMode  not found instead

Comment: That class should be part of hibernate-jpa-2.1-api which comes with hibernate-entitymanager but has compile time scope. Try to add it to `pom.xml` as mentiond in edit.