# web application with vaadin and orm (from visual paradigm) doesn't work - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org / orm / PersistentException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, orm, vaadin

My situation is:

- orm.jar and classes exported from a visual paradigm project (orm.jar in java build path)
- user interface created with Vaadin Framework.
- SQL server (XAMPP) in localhost.
- Using Eclipse EE, Java, and DAO pattern.

I am creating a web application. I'm using Apache tomcat 7, when I fill in data through the user interface to create a category, with the server running, by clicking the "create category" button (this should create a category in the database), this does not do anything, and shows the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org / orm / PersistentException

SERVER LOG:

```
ago 06, 2018 12:14:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMACIÓN: Ha comenzado la recarga de Contexto [/YoutubeEvolution]
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing AtmosphereFramework
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
addAtmosphereHandler
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereHandler 
com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path: 

ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
addAtmosphereHandler
INFORMACIÓN: Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to 
AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
autoConfigureService
INFORMACIÓN: Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.util.VoidAnnotationProcessor 
for processing annotation
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.util.ForkJoinPool <init>
INFORMACIÓN: Using ForkJoinPool  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool. Set the 
org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads to -1 to fully use its 
power.
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework initWebSocket
INFORMACIÓN: Installed WebSocketProtocol 
org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport <init>
INFORMACIÓN: JSR 356 Mapping path /{path}
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN: Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptors
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor 
Support
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default 
Response's Headers Interceptor
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : 
Browser Padding Interceptor Support
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : 
Android Interceptor Support
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN: Dropping Interceptor 
org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE 
Interceptor Support
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP 
Interceptor Support
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework 
newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere 
JavaScript Protocol

ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection

ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN:    org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFORMACIÓN: Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor CORS Interceptor Support with priority FIRST_BEFORE_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Default Response's Headers Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser Padding Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Android Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor SSE Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor JSONP Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser disconnection detection with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Broadcaster Shared List Resources: false
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Shared ExecutorService supported: true
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Messaging ExecutorService Pool Size unavailable - Not instance of ThreadPoolExecutor
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Using AtmosphereResurceFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAtmosphereResourceFactory
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: HttpSession supported: true
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFORMACIÓN: Atmosphere Framework 2.4.11.vaadin2 started.
ago 06, 2018 12:14:54 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMACIÓN: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
ago 06, 2018 12:14:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMACIÓN: Se ha completado la recarga de este Contexto
ago 06, 2018 12:16:45 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration checkProductionMode
ADVERTENCIA: 
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================
ago 06, 2018 12:45:54 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
GRAVE: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/orm/PersistentException
    at evolutionYoutube.Aniadir_Categoria.crear_categoria(Aniadir_Categoria.java:39)
    at evolutionYoutube.Aniadir_Categoria$1.buttonClick(Aniadir_Categoria.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.orm.PersistentException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 45 more
```

Can anybody help me? I need to solve this error to complete my project

Comment: Is your pom file including the persistence api jar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684565/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-persistence-sharedcachemode ?

Comment: Yes, but i'm using an external api, external jar exported by Visual Paradigm: "orm.jar". In the classes, i use "import org.orm.PersistentException" for example. This is inside the api of the jar file, but when i do a maven build 
this library is not recognized. 
I think it may be necessary to include the library in the pom, even if it's external, but in that case, I would not know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Solved: right click on the project, run as ..., run configurations, tomcat v7.0 server, classpath, add entries: orm jar, end.

Comment: Feel free to mark own answer as accepted to indicate you are not searching for further answers.