# How to config JPA in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I try to implement jpa in my application by tutorial from

[dev-calibry](https://devcolibri.com/spring-data-jpa-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1/)

So, my DataConfig looks like this:

```
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("ru.sbrf.risks.services.data")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence")
public class DataConfig {
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "db.hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "db.hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));

        return properties;
    }
}
```

But, there is error message when I try to launch my application.
Build war-> start on embeded tomcat.

> > Connected to server [2018-09-26 09:54:32,631] Artifact unnamed: Artifact is being deployed, please wait... 26-Sep-2018 09:54:34.460
> >     WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance
> >     Name = LanitBPM Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal
> >     instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "3" for
> >     "maxActive" property, which is being ignored. 26-Sep-2018 09:54:34.587
> >     INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
> >     scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
> >     logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
> >     found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
> >     startup time and JSP compilation time. 26-Sep-2018 09:54:34.814 INFO
> >     [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext
> >     Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 26-Sep-2018
> >     09:54:34.873 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh
> >     Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 26
> >     09:54:34 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy 26-Sep-2018 09:54:35.051
> >     INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions
> >     Registering annotated classes: [class
> >     ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.service.config.ServiceConfig,class
> >     ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence.config.DataConfig,class
> >     ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.web.config.WebConfig] 26-Sep-2018
> >     09:54:35.583 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.refresh
> >     Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> >     refresh attempt:
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
> >     to parse configuration class
> >     [ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence.config.DataConfig]; nested
> >     exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect
> >     annotated methods on class
> >     ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence.config.DataConfig 26-Sep-2018
> >     09:54:35.596 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext
> >     Context initialization failed 
> >     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
> >     to parse configuration class
> >     [ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence.config.DataConfig]; nested
> >     exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect
> >     annotated methods on class
> >     ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence.config.DataConfig     at
> >     org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
> >     ... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect
> >     annotated methods on class
> >     ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence.config.DataConfig     at
> >     org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:380)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
> >       ... 54 more [2018-09-26 09:54:35,640] Artifact unnamed: Error during
> >     artifact deployment. See server log for details. Caused by:
> >     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager     at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
> >     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
> >     org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152)
> >       ... 59 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager     at
> >     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
> >       ... 63 more
> >
> > 26-Sep-2018 09:54:35.602 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
> >     listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
> >     appropriate container log file 26-Sep-2018 09:54:35.603 SEVERE [RMI
> >     TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context []
> >     startup failed due to previous errors 26-Sep-2018 09:54:42.439 INFO
> >     [localhost-startStop-1]
> >     org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
> >     application directory [C:\java\apache-tomcat-8.5.29\webapps\manager]
> >     26-Sep-2018 09:54:42.629 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
> >     org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
> >     web application directory
> >     [C:\java\apache-tomcat-8.5.29\webapps\manager] has finished in [189]
> >     ms

If there is better way to use jpa with spring-mvc? (no spring-boot)

app.properties:

```
#DB properties: 
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb 
db.username=root 
db.password=111111

#Hibernate Configuration:    
db.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect   
db.hibernate.show_sql=true    
db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan=ru.sbrf.risks.services.data
db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
```

pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring.data>
        <swagger.version>2.7.0</swagger.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SWAGGER-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${swagger.version}</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${swagger.version}</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--DATA BASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.9.6</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what's the value for `db.driver` and other properties? and also I think you should change `@ComponentScan("ru.sbrf.risks.services.data")` to `@ComponentScan("ru.sbrf.risks")`

Comment: @ComponentScan is correct, db.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Your root cause is this: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager`. Check if you have configured your dependencies (e.g. via Maven or Gradle) correctly.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht I think, that this exception occours after Failed to introspect annotated methods on.. exception. Is it may be cause, why JpaTransactionManager not created and not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSource bean - **OK**

PlatformTransactionManager/JpaTransactionManager - **not completed**:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - **not completed**

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan("some package(s)");
    entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManager.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return entityManager;
}
```

And I don't use next class annotations:
`@ComponentScan(" ... ") //you use scan in entityManagerFactory`
`@PropertySource(" ... ") //you use env.getProperty`
`@EnableJpaRepositories(" ... ")`

I use next packages concerning Jpa/Hibernate:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: SPRING_VERSION
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: SPRING_DATA_VERSION
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: SPRING_VERSION

compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: MYSQL_CONNECTOR_VERSION

compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: HIBERNATE_VERSION
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: HIBERNATE_VERSION
```

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Converter

Comment: I think that is your solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40685168/4573580
It was not required for me. I think it was in another package from dependencies or another package(s) required it and loaded automatically.