# UnsatisfiedDependencyException of JpaRepositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I'm writing a jpa repostory example and I'm getting a runtime exception of type UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

Here is my program:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { PersonRepository.class, ProfessionRepository.class})
@ComponentScan( basePackageClasses =MyService.class)
public class SpringDataJpa  {
        public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringDataJpa.class);
        service myService = applicationContext.getBean(MyService.class);
    }
}
```

The service interface:

```
public interface service {
    void add( Person person );
    List<Person> getListOfPersons();
}
```

The implementation that throw the exception:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements service {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Override
    public void add( Person person ){
        System.out.println("saved");
    }
    @Override
    public List<Person> getListOfPersons() {
        return  null;
    }
}
```

The repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

}
@Repository
public interface ProfessionRepository extends JpaRepository<Profession, Integer> {

}
```

The exception i'm getting:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'personRepository': Post-processing of merged
>   bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/SynchronizationType

As I checked this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684565/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-persistence-sharedcachemode?rq=1), I added the proposed dependencies.  My dependencies in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.197</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

How to solve this error?

My second question is: should we use  `@EnableJpaRepositories` if we use Spring Boot?

Comment: You're mixing incompatible versions together. For example, some of the spring deps have version LATEST, others have 5.1.7.RELEASE, others have 5.1.5.RELEASE. Dont. And don't use the obsolete hibernate-jpa-2.0-api, which is an old version of javax.persistence-api

Comment: @JBNizet I corrected my pom files with Latest version for all the spring dependencies, I deleted the hibertnate dependencie. But the problem is the same.

Comment: I know that i can use spring boot to ease the dependencies management, but for learning purpose I'm writing the dependencies myself.

Comment: The class SynchronizationType is part of the javax.persistence-api dependency. So I don't see how you could have this exception if you indeed have that jar file in your runtime classpath.

Comment: just to be precise, when i corrected my pom.xml file, I'm getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;

Comment: That means you still have an old version of the JPA API in your runtime classpath, hiding the newest one.

Comment: @JBNizet i forgot to instantiate bymyself a datasource and a an entitymagerfactory bean. I thought that without those beans we can at least inject jpa repository to a  service bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a datasource and an entityManagerFactory beans were missing.
To solve my problem i added the followed code in my configuration class:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource firstDataSource (){
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ride_tracker?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory( DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("data");
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following version, SynchronizationType is available since 2.1.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```